# Splitting a substring in PowerShell for parsing to CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, parsing, split, substring

I'm trying to split a part of my substring (below `'Event'  =$_.Substring(23).Trim()`) and can't seem to figure it out. I've tried `Trim()`, `Split()`, `TrimEnd()` and various other nested `foreach` statements with no good results.

Right now the code takes a log file and parses out just the date and an event. I want to further parse the event, starting with "General" which will be the type of event.

Here is the current log file snippet.

```
2017-09-21 14:45:00.778 General Removed local reservations for command with future handle: 7129d084-8b68-4b3e-9df7-54832a4590f1 Display: False  
2017-09-21 14:45:00.778 Debug   Published update SetLightTowerState (id=7129d084-8b68-4b3e-9df7-54832a4590f1) [100.0 %] RanToCompletion - Complete (RanToCompletion)    Display: False  
2017-09-21 14:45:00.778 General Command: SetLightTowerState status: RanToCompletion (id=7129d084-8b68-4b3e-9df7-54832a4590f1)   Display: False  Source: Primary\Printer Light Tower
```

All logs are stored into a folder and I foreach them and export to a csv with this.

```
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem $fileDirectory) {
    (Get-Content $fileDirectory$file -Raw) -split '(?m)(?=^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})'
        Where {$_} |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'Date/Time' = " " + $_.Substring(0, 23)
                'Event' = $_.Substring(23).Trim()

                # Want to further split the string up here and make new Columns
                # statement type', 'statement', 'display' 'source' etc...

            }
        } | Export-Csv C:\fileLocation\$file.csv -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Current results look like this:

[image: MyExcelSnippit_Photo]

Comment: "*General Removed local reservations for command with future handle: 7129d084-8b68-4b3e-9df7-54832a4590f1 Display: False*" - is this supposed to have an obvious 'statement', 'statement type', 'source' and 'etc' ? Because I can only see 'display' in there..? I get that you don't know how to parse it, but what's your question? What was going wrong? You clearly know how to use the relevant string processing tools .. and you haven't made it clear what it should do or what output you want .. ?

Comment: Ok so I'm seeing that as it currently parses, It gets rid of the tab-delimited format between General Removed, and makes it into GeneralRemoved when outputing to excel. I understand that I am making a hash table where Event is a substring starting from character 23 and trimming the end so it fits better in the Excel cells.  What I want to do is keep the tab-delimited format somehow, and split the substring from character 23 to the first tab. Then I would have a column for Event type (general) and Event (Removed local...)  .  Hope this better explains it.  Thanks!

Comment: If they are tab delimited why don't you just open them in Excel with the delimited text importer? Or use `Import-Csv -Delimiter "\`t"` in PowerShell to get fields to work with?

Comment: For one thing there seems to be a `|` missing at the end of the `-split` line. But as TessellatingHeckler already said: why don't you simply import the delimited file as a delimited file? That way you'd get timestamp, event type and message as separate fields and could then further break down the message as required. For help with the latter you'd need to provide further information on which way you want the different messages split, though.

Comment: To be clear: The log folder contains several logs with consistent naming conventions. Importing as tab delimited will work for one of the files, but the rest need the date extracted since they are not exactly tab delimited in all places. Therefore I chose to stick with extracting the date and splitting the rest of the information off to deal with later. What I need help with is further splitting the rest of the information into categories based on tabs or spaces within the information.  I may have to treat each file differently with if/else or some other way.

Comment: What do you expect us to do? Provide you with a magic "split my log files whichever way I want" spell? Doesn't work that way.